# How to set up an SQL table(s) structure for product categories?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and I am currently trying to make a simple product page in PHP and MySql. Now I have a `products` table which has my product `id`, `name`, `price` and `stock`.

**Edit: Sample `products` tables:**

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|    id    |         name        |       price    |     stock    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1    |    Guess T-Shirt    |       10       |      100     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The thing I'm trying to do is having different categories for the products, such that each product can fall into multiple categories.

Here are the options that each product will have:

[image]

Now as you see, there are different categories each with sub-categories.

On first thought, I wanted to  have a table with all these categories as rows and a foreign key to `id` from my `products` table. I realized it would not be the best way to do it, but I also don't know what would be the right way to do it.

I apologize in advance if the question might be irrelevant. I don't have any codes to show, I just need some input on the correct database structure.

If you require more detail, please comment down and I'll update this post.
Thanks

Comment: You should include some sample data.

Comment: You could have categories table with id, parent_id and category_name (allows simple N-level trees). Create product_category_mapping table and store product id and mapped category id. Solved.

Comment: Have a look at this article (and the two before it) if you want in depth description of understanding database relationships. It will definitely help you design your databases properly http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Edited with a sample table that I currently have

Comment: @nTuply great that work for you but you should read samrap link too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I did. Thanks Samrap. Great tutorial with great content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a `product` table with this fields

- product_id `primary key`
- Visibility, probably boolean
- Stock, probably boolean
- Discount, integer
- Remarks, probably boolean

Then a table `category` for the left side of the menu

- category_id `primary key`
- name {basic, collection, shirts, trouser, dresses}

and a pivot table `product_category`

- product_id
- category_id

Finally your query will be

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_category pc
        ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE 
     p.Visibility = @visibilty  
 AND p.Stock = @Stock
 AND p.Discount = @Discount
 AND p.Remarks = @Remarks
 AND pc.Category_id in (@category);
```

Comment: You might want to mention the `product_category` table is called a pivot table, that way the OP can Google pivot table to learn more.

Comment: Makes sense. However I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by `name{...}` and the pivot table `product_category`. Could you please give some more explanation on these? Thanks :) Edit: Didn't see Styphon's comment. I'll Google that

Comment: `name {...}` mean there is a row for each entry on your `Menu` left side. That allow you for example prepare the webpage reading from that table and easy to update if later you want change/remove categories. You can read pivot [**HERE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) the idea is each `product` can have several `category` you will add a row for each pair you have. for example `{product 't-shirt', category 'Basic Collection'} {t-shirt, 'T-Shirts'}`

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thanks